# Rewrite SQL statement from USING to ON

Tags: php, mysql, using

Hey guys. Having trouble here. Have to webhotels with same MySQL and PHPmyadmin versions, but reacts different. Mayb something with the MySQL.ini.

How can I rewrite this into ON, from Using.

```
SELECT wiederquist_elearn_question.idelearn_question AS idelearn_question, idelearn_answer, idelearn_user, name, email, address, zip, city, phone, extra, user_created_time, newsletter, answertime, title, description, illustration, answertext, correct
FROM wiederquist_elearn_user
INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_question_answered
USING ( idelearn_user ) 
INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_question
USING ( idelearn_question ) 
INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_answer
USING ( idelearn_answer ) 
WHERE name IS NOT NULL 
AND idelearn =1
```

Hope you can help me here.Thank you.

Edit:

Now I got this, but it shows 11.700 results, and it should only show 2. But it is the right results, their just looping.

```
SELECT wiederquist_elearn_question.idelearn_question AS idelearn_question, name, email, address, zip, city, phone, extra, user_created_time, newsletter, answertime, title, description, illustration, answertext, correct
FROM wiederquist_elearn_user
INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_question_answered ON wiederquist_elearn_question_answered.idelearn_user
INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_question ON wiederquist_elearn_question.idelearn_question
INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_answer ON wiederquist_elearn_answer.idelearn_answer
WHERE name IS NOT NULL 
AND idelearn =1
```

DB Tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `wiederquist_elearn` (
  `ideLearn` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'id',
  `name` varchar(250) default 'uden navn' COMMENT '''Kursus nav',
  `correctRequired` int(1) default '0' COMMENT '''Korrekt svar påkrævet for at fortsætt',
  `successNumber` int(11) default '0' COMMENT '''Antal korrekte svar krævet for "bestået',
  `displayMode` varchar(45) default 'single' COMMENT '''Ved systemets opstart, enkeltvisning eller listevisnin',
  `repeatable` int(1) default '0' COMMENT 'Kan kurset gentages',
  `learning` int(1) default '0',
  `mandatory` int(1) default '0',
  `errorMessage` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ideLearn`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

CREATE TABLE `wiederquist_elearn_answer` (
  `idelearn_answer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `answertext` text,
  `correct` int(1) default NULL,
  `idelearn_question` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `order` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `correctText` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idelearn_answer`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE `wiederquist_elearn_question` (
  `idelearn_question` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` text,
  `description` text,
  `idelearn` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `illustration` varchar(150) default 'dummy.jpg',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idelearn_question`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE `wiederquist_elearn_question_answered` (
  `idelearn_question_answered` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `idelearn_user` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `idelearn_question` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `idelearn_answer` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `answertime` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idelearn_question_answered`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE `wiederquist_elearn_user` (
  `idelearn_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `address` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `zip` int(4) default NULL,
  `city` varchar(90) default NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `extra` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `user_created_time` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `newsletter` int(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idelearn_user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Comment: can you paste the related db tables and relations?

Answer (score 1):

I did it! yay

```
SELECT wiederquist_elearn_question.idelearn_question AS idelearn_question, wiederquist_elearn_answer.idelearn_answer, wiederquist_elearn_user.idelearn_user, name, email, address, zip, city, phone, extra, user_created_time, newsletter, answertime, title, description, illustration, answertext, correct
FROM wiederquist_elearn_user
INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_question_answered
USING ( idelearn_user ) 
INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_question
USING ( idelearn_question ) 
INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_answer ON wiederquist_elearn_answer.idelearn_answer = wiederquist_elearn_question_answered.idelearn_answer
WHERE name IS NOT NULL and idelearn = 1
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Then it was the alias that messed it up. Weird how differnet servers can interpret differently.

Comment: hope my simple example makes it clearer for you. i usually use the first letter of the table for an alias if possible so customers c, in your case with your long table names do something like wiederquist_elearn_question_answered as weqa, wiederquist_elearn_question as weq etc...

Comment: It makes sense. tank you very much

Comment: no problem - just remember to alias all the columns in your select and order by too :P

Answer (score 0):

You should use INNER JOIN jointablename ON jointablename.join_id = tablename.id, for this case query will looks like:

```
SELECT weq.idelearn_question AS idelearn_question, idelearn_answer, weu.idelearn_user 
as idelearn_uder, name, email, address, zip, city, phone, extra, user_created_time, 
newsletter, answertime, title, description, illustration, answertext, correct
    FROM wiederquist_elearn_user AS weu
       INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_question_answered AS weqa 
           ON weu.idelearn_user = weu.idelearn_user
      INNER JOIN wiederquist_elearn_question AS weq 
           ON weq.idelearn_question = (table your need to join).idelearn_question
and so on..
```

Comment: Can you give me an working example. Really need to learn this. I tried to insert the table name i need to join with no luck.

Comment: I do not know the structure of tables you are using, so I can write wrong ON clause.